# Error in R: cannot find laveneTest function. How to solve?

Tags: r, error, car

I need to run the Lavene's test to check equal variances of a linear model in R, but I get an error message that R cannot find the function laveneTest. I already checked older posts from people with the same problem, but I could not solve it. I already installed the "car" package, and I also installed the "hms" and "reshape2" package as I found suggestions in previous posts that this could solve the issue.
Do you have an idea why it is not working? I am using R version 4.1.3.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend spelling the function correctly: `leveneTest`.

Comment: Also, after installing the `car` package, make sure you load the `car` package first with e.g. `library(car)` or `require(car)`.